# Old O level mechanics problem (imperial units) regarding magnitude and direction of resultant acceleration. Is the solution wrong?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

First time on the physics side so apologies in advance for any errors this post may contain.

Question is as follows:

A particle of mass $3\text{ lb}$ hangs from a fixed point by a string, and is pulled aside by a horizontal force until the string makes an angle of $30^o$ with the vertical. If the mass is then in equilibrium, find the size of the horizontal force and the tension in the string.

If the string be now cut, the horizontal force remaining unaltered, what will be the magnitude and direction of the resulting acceleration.

Solutions give:

$\sqrt{3}\text{ lb. wt.}$

$2\sqrt{3}\text{ lb. wt.}$

$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\text{ ft/sec}^2 \text{ at 30}^o\text{ to vertical}$

I have been able to calculate the first two solutions correctly, using a simple diagram and basic trigonometry, but cannot get an answer to agree with the last part, although I do get the same direction. My reasoning has been that if the string is cut then a resultant equal and opposite to the tension will exist - hence the agreement with direction. However, try as I might I cannot get an answer for acceleration to agree with the text. I get $\frac{2\sqrt{3}\text{g}}{3}\text{ft/sec}^2$ (using $\text{Resultant}=\text{ma}$) but I'm sure this isn't right.

For those of you who are able to help me it is worth nothing that $1\text{ lb. wt.}= 32 \text{ poundals}=32\text{ lb-ft/sec}^2$. Therefore $\text{g}=32\text{ft/sec}^2$.

Many thanks in advance for any advice given.

Comment: It would be better if you provided your work/thoughts on the last part, otherwise we are left to guess how you tried solving it.

Comment: Apologies, I just constructed a simple diagram and used trig for right angled triangle to obtain horizontal force and tension.